# Firefox Titlebar disapearing randomly - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: firefox, titlebar

Anyone experiencing the same? My issue:

Using Firefox in Ubuntu 18.04 and Title bar disappears randomly. Also while Title bar is missing Firefox window never comes to top if under another window.
Customize > Title Bar Checkbox == ON.

I was trying to use F11 with no success.

Workarounds that works:

1. Grab one of tabs and move outside of existing window (title bar restored), then other tabs moved to such window are OK.
2. Go to Customize > Title Bar checkbox (is ON) / deactivate and activate again. After "checkbox restart" Title Bar is restored back.

Any clue? Any hints please?
All SW up to date.

Thanks!

Comment: There is an extension to keep FF on top: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/always-on-top/

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the extension. Unfortunately it is not what I am looking for.

Comment: *Anyone experiencing the same?* Yes., Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon (Ubuntu 22.04). .

Answer (score 0):

******Try reinstalling the firefox******

first purge

```
sudo apt purge firefox
```

then try clearing the cache of file

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

then install it again

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

Comment: Thank you for approaching. Unfortunately, this is not a working solution (does not help) nor direction I expect in Linux.